# Internationalization Best Practices / Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I am new to ruby & rails and have started building an application.

My goal is to build this in a way I can easily translate the contents of the rails app and display the website contents in a locale preferred by registered user.

Appreciate any inputs on some of the best practices or references to any documentation to read, to build a web application that can be easily translated?

Thanks,
Krish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the [Rails Internationalization (I18n) API](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html). It does everything you've described.

Comment: Thanks idlefingers. That helps. Do you have any suggestions / watchouts / links for tranlsations reltaed to specific languages, say, Chinese / Vietnamese / Japanese etc.,?

Comment: It's just some sort of hello world.
There's no practices describing how to organize files/backends/locale_data when you have absolutely different languages (let's say: English, Russian, Arabic, Chinese) — that's a pretty complex problem I guess (english is simple, not so featured like the other ones).

Answer (score 3):

Also check out [Globalize3](https://github.com/svenfuchs/globalize3), it became a standard for model translations. Very useful.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ready_for_i18n](https://github.com/zigzag/ready_for_i18n)  plugin that convert your erb to desired form.It saves some time.

Comment: Will definitely give it a try Amar. This looks interesting. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'd definetely watch this talk: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTu4iHWGDyE

Answer (score 1):

Here are some tips or best practices I noted while working through Internationalization of a **Rails app**. (It's possible that some of them are now outdated).

Before I get into a list here's some clarification between localization and translation that was helpful to me:

**Definitions:**

App localization and model translations are separate concerns. Figure out which one of those (or both) it is, that you need.

The way I use them here:

- App localization: Localization your app to a locale.
- Model translation: Translation your model/data into a language.

Example: Give me the french translation (model translation) of the resource in my Spanish site (app localization)

I use [Globalize](https://github.com/globalize/globalize) for model translations.

**Helpful Tips/ Best Practices:**

Some of the following are clearly just helpful tips while working in the Context of Rails + Globalize, some of them might be more than that... possibly best practices.

- `I18n.locale` refers to and sets the locale of the app. When using Globalize, `Globalize.locale` refers to and sets the locale for model/data translations.
- Set both `I18n.locale` and `Globalize.locale` on every request. Since these variables are set in `Thread`, it will avoid some hard-to-replicate bugs.
- Set `Globalize.locale` to `I18n.locale` right after setting `I18n.locale`. This allows for model translations to default to the locale of the app. (On my Spanish site, I expect data to be in Spanish, by default).
- Change `Globalize.locale` (and not`I18n.locale`) to change model translation.
- Reset `I18n.locale` and `Globalize.locale` after every test. In rspec

  ```
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.after(:each) do 
      I18n.locale = :en
      Globalize.locale = :en
    end
  end
  ```
- Either use subdomain, or subfolder in the url to refer to the locale of the app.
- Use a language parameter to specify the language of the data.
- When you work on your rails app, you will probably use `default_url_options` to use `I18n.locale` as the default locale parameter for your route / path helpers. However this doesn't work in tests. I picked up a solution from [this](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/255) github issue on rspec-rails.

  I monkey patch `ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet` like so:

  ```
  class ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet
    def url_for_with_locale_fix(options={})
      url_for_without_locale_fix(options.merge(:locale => I18n.locale))
    end

    alias_method_chain :url_for, :locale_fix
  end
  ```
- Set up a translate helper `t` as a wrapper around the I18n.t method

  ```
  module I18nHelper
    def t string, options = {}
      I18n.t string, options
    end
  end

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include I18nHelper
  end
  ```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: You provided the wrong link (fighter thoughts), please use the correct link: https://gist.github.com/gaganawhad/5584723

Answer (score -1):

This is mini-pattern I use. You can check it out: http://developers-note.blogspot.com/2012/01/rails-i18n-good-practice.html